# Facebook php SDK v4.0 codeigniter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I integrated facebook php v4.0 in codeigniter. In localhost, Pages are loading all fine and also I can get redirect url. But when I take site to online. Site opens blank without any error. Then I unload facebook library from controller and pages load correctly. I think its problem with facebook library. Below is my facebook library :

```html
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
if ( session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE ) {
session_start();
}
// Autoload the required files
require_once( APPPATH . 'libraries/facebook/vendor/autoload.php' );
require_once( APPPATH . 'libraries/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once( APPPATH . 'libraries/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( APPPATH . 'libraries/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );

require_once( APPPATH . 'libraries/Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php' );
require_once( APPPATH . 'libraries/Facebook/Entities/SignedRequest.php' );

require_once( APPPATH . 'libraries/Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( APPPATH . 'libraries/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( APPPATH . 'libraries/Facebook/FacebookSignedRequestFromInputHelper.php' );
require_once( APPPATH . 'libraries/Facebook/FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper.php' );

require_once( APPPATH . 'libraries/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( APPPATH . 'libraries/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( APPPATH . 'libraries/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( APPPATH . 'libraries/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( APPPATH . 'libraries/Facebook/FacebookOtherException.php' );
require_once( APPPATH . 'libraries/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( APPPATH . 'libraries/Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( APPPATH . 'libraries/Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );

use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
class Facebook {
var $ci;
var $helper;
var $session;
var $permissions;
public function __construct() {
$this->ci =& get_instance();
$this->permissions = $this->ci->config->item('permissions', 'facebook');
// Initialize the SDK
        
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( $this->ci->config->item('api_id', 'facebook'), $this->ci->config->item('app_secret', 'facebook') );
// Create the login helper and replace REDIRECT_URI with your URL
// Use the same domain you set for the apps 'App Domains'
// e.g. $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://example.com/redirect' );
$this->helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( $this->ci->config->item('redirect_url', 'facebook') );

if ( $this->ci->session->userdata('fb_token') ) {
$this->session = new FacebookSession( $this->ci->session->userdata('fb_token') );
// Validate the access_token to make sure it's still valid
try {
if ( ! $this->session->validate() ) {
$this->session = null;
}
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
// Catch any exceptions
$this->session = null;
}
} else {
// No session exists
try {
$this->session = $this->helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
// When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
// When validation fails or other local issues
}
}
if ( $this->session ) {
  
$this->ci->session->set_userdata( 'fb_token', $this->session->getToken() );
$this->session = new FacebookSession( $this->session->getToken() );
}
}
/**
* Returns the login URL.
*/
public function login_url() {
return $this->helper->getLoginUrl( $this->permissions );
}
/**
* Returns the current user's info as an array.
*/
public function get_user() {
if ( $this->session ) {
/**
* Retrieve User’s Profile Information
*/
// Graph API to request user data
$request = ( new FacebookRequest( $this->session, 'GET', '/me' ) )->execute();
// Get response as an array
$user = $request->getGraphObject()->asArray();
return $user;
}
return false;
}
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is that your server don't have errors turned on so you don't see them

Comment: But i can see some other errors while i m in testing.

Comment: You have a small letter in your require 'vendor/autoload' it might be the problem if you were developing on windows & your production runs on Linux

Comment: I am developing on windows

Comment: Is your production server linux ??

Comment: If you haven't already you should also check the error log from your webserver, sometimes it can provide additional information about the error. Also if you have shell access on your sever you should run php on it from the command line. I've had to do that in the past to find errors.

Answer (score 3):

Check your index.php file and make sure environment is set to 'development' its likey your local server is configured to show php errors but your web server isn't.

The index.php file is at the root of your application and should have a comment block called "APPLICATION ENVIRONMENT" which is where you define your environment. Below you will see this line:

```
define(ENVIRONMENT,'development'); //or 'testing' or 'production'
```

Ensure that this is using 'development'. Additionally below check the block called 'ERROR REPORTING' which has a switch statement underneath. I set mine up to look like this which means that if ENVIRONMENT is set to either 'development' or 'testing' all errors will be shown.

```
switch (ENVIRONMENT)
{
    case 'development':
    case 'testing':
        ini_set('display_errors',true);
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
    break;
    case 'production':
        ini_set('display_errors',false);
        error_reporting(0);
    break;

    default:
        exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
}
```

Comment: I can't get what you are trying tell. In index.html. Not index.php in codeigniter APPPATH.

Comment: Yes. This is same as mine. Error reporting is 0.

Comment: Please read the answer again. If error_reporting is set to 0 then it should be obvious that no errors will be shown. Set environment to development so error_reporting is switched to 1

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure your php version is 5.4 or greater on your server.

Facebook sdk use curl. So make sure you've installed and enable curl extension.
You can check it by echoing `phpinfo()`. If your server is linux, then you can install it like that.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
sudo service apache2 restart
```

To check error message, add these lines to top of your index.php.

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Hope it will be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with above answers regarding setting your env to development in config, plus checking with your server settings and allow php errors temporarily to make sure, but also, one of the most likely issues would be coming from your paths.

ie
APPPATH . 'libraries/facebook/vendor/autoload.php'

Make sure APPPATH is correct for your server, ie if your server is running in a LAMP distribution, and your localhost is running WAMP/XAMPP etc, than your APPPATH might be set to C:\wamp\www\yoursiteroot\ whereas your root folder might be /var/www, you can see they're bound to be much different

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the new client redirect url on app config page.

Comment: in which page your application fails ,login page or url redirect page

Comment: site even doesnot open after loading facebook library and also doesn't show any error. But when i remove facebook library from controller then it loads perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In `index.php` change:

```
define(ENVIRONMENT,'testing');
```

As you said earlier under Mike Miller's answear, in your index.php you contains the code:

```
switch (ENVIRONMENT)
{
    case 'development':
    case 'testing':
        ini_set('display_errors',true);
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
    break;
    case 'production':
        ini_set('display_errors',false);
        error_reporting(0);
    break;

    default:
        exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
}
```

right? And you have your ENVIRONMENT constant set as  **development**. If you set it to **testing**, that will set

```
ini_set('display_errors',true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

and the server will display the error(s) that brake(s) your page. 
You said ***Site opens blank without any error***. That may be due to error that doesn't get displayed. So setting your CodeIgniter **ENVIRONMENT** to **testing** will not solve the errors, but will make them visible, so you would know what's going on.